# PYTHON - Can I run an event listener to listen for errors throughout my script?

Tags: python, selenium, event-handling

Sorry if this has been asked before, I couldn't find anything related to this on Python and regarding using this with Selenium.

I'm running a Selenium script on a particular website but after staying on the site too long, the site asks me to login again. This event gives me a stale element reference error midway during the running of the code, but all I have to do is enter a password, enter, and it brings me back to exactly where I was (e.g where the script was running until it was prompted for login details).

My question is, is it possible to create an event listener that listens for this particular error THROUGHOUT the entire script and then does a function? Obviously, I know there is error handling, but to my knowledge, that doesn't work continuously... unless I wrap my entire script around a try...except block, which I'd rather not do.

Are there any options? Am I missing something obvious?
Here is what I've tried so far with the simplegui package, but I received a CannotSendRequest(self.__state) error upon running.

```
timer = simplegui.create_timer(2000, check)
timer.start()
```

Comment: Which line gives you `StaleElementRefferenceException`?

Comment: Each script should launch a new browser so that each run is clean. If you are doing this and you are still staying on the site too long then that's likely the problem... shorten your tests. Another option is to find the cookie that contains the timeout and edit it to never expire.

Comment: It could be any line of my code, since the timer on the site I'm testing on expires after a certain (long) period of time, my program could be at any point of the code. I think what you're suggesting is to include an error handler at that point of the code that gives me the StaleElementRefferenceException, but since that error could arise at any point, I cannot have that error handler be at a specific point of the script. It needs to be constantly running, checking to see if an element exists (the 'check' function). @JeffC unfortunately, I'm not authorized to make that edit

Comment: You control the cookies on your machine. You can edit them all you want.

Comment: @JeffC, ok.. I'm not really familiar with what you're suggesting. Could you point me in the right direction, what should I search? Really want to give it a try. Thank you